# How to pass content property of Control as CommandParameter WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, radio-button

I have WPF project that has 19 radio button. I want to set Command property each of them.
To separate all command actions, I want to send ***RadioButton Content*** property as a CommandParameter.

I try to define setter for CommandParameter property and I set `{Binding Path=Content}`for Value as you can see below.

But it is not work.

```
 <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"/>
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=Content}"/>
    </Style>
          

 <RadioButton Content="Area"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Unit"
                         Grid.Row="1"/>
            
            <RadioButton Content="Transom Count"
                         Grid.Row="2"
                         CommandParameter="Transom Count"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Mullion Count"
                         Grid.Row="3"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Transom And Mulliom Count"
                         Grid.Row="4"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Frame Count"
                         Grid.Row="5"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Frame + Transom + Mullion Count"
                         Grid.Row="6"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Corner Points"
                         Grid.Row="7"/>
            <RadioButton Content="T Connections"
                         Grid.Row="8"/>

            <RadioButton Content="Left"
                         Grid.Column="1"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Right"
                         Grid.Column="1"
                         Grid.Row="1"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Top"
                         Grid.Column="1"
                         Grid.Row="2"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Bottom"
                         Grid.Column="1"
                         Grid.Row="3"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Perimeter"
                         Grid.Column="1"
                         Grid.Row="4"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Transom Length"
                         Grid.Column="1"
                         Grid.Row="5"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Mullion Length"
                         Grid.Column="1"
                         Grid.Row="6"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Transom + Mullion Length"
                         Grid.Column="1"
                         Grid.Row="7"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Perimeter + Transom + Mullion Length"
                         Grid.Column="1"
                         Grid.Row="8"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```xml
 <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"/>
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    </Style>
```

Comment: It is perfectly worked. Many thanx.

Comment: @Gokhan I would also advise you, instead of the RadioButton collection, to use ItemsControl in the item template of which will be RadioButton.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, you can pass the Content property of a control as the CommandParameter by binding it to the CommandParameter property of the command you are using.

Here's an example using a Button control:

In this example:

MyCommand is the command you've defined in your ViewModel.
CommandParameter is set to the Content property of the Button.
RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self} specifies that you're binding to the Content property of the current control (Button in this case).
Make sure your ViewModel has a property to receive this CommandParameter.

Remember, the CommandParameter is the additional parameter you pass to your command method in the ViewModel. Adjust the bindings accordingly based on the control you are using and the structure of your ViewModel.

Comment: many thanx for attention and  additional explanatory information.